# Eclipse complains about getActionBar overridden method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, overriding

android.app.Activity has `getActionBar()` method which returns `android.app.ActionBar`. Then a library project contains a custom activity which extends from Activity. This custom activity class has a `getActionBar()` method(without @OVERRIDE) which returns a custom ActionBar, not `android.app.ActionBar`. Then Eclipse complains about incompatible return type for the getActionBar(). Because this is an external library project I don't want to change the name getActionBar() and custom ActionBar class. Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible. Change the name getActionBar(). 
[Defining Methods in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: This library was developed for before 3.0 when ActionBar was introduced, so there is conflict. Changing API level to 8 solved the problem.